# JavaFX is it sill relative

Tags: java, javafx

Working on this desktop application, every thing is going great.  Had some troubles her and there, but fixed every single on of them. 
The only problem is that my app look ugly, that is what my boss thinking. 
Done some research found javaFX but a lot of forums calling it dead or dying
is true ??

And if not any one has a good tutorial on it

```
JAVAFX
```

Comment: JAVA FX is part of Java 8 and meant to replace Swing , so it isn't about to die.

Comment: At least: _JavaFX is the next step in the evolution of Java as a rich client platform. It is designed to provide a lightweight, hardware-accelerated Java UI platform for enterprise business applications._ [Source](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/javafx-overview-2158620.html)

Comment: It is relevant. We have done a number of commercial database / erp like applications using it as a front end. Works great. Does have a small learning curve, just like swing, jsf, gwt or vaddin do but once you get the neck of it, it is just great.

Comment: "Dead" how?  It's part of Java 8, and Java 9 which will have an end of life in something like 10 years or longer!  So sick of these damn "web guys" keep trying to kill off other tech by calling it "dead", even if it isn't directly competing with their precious framework-of-the-month of choice.  The fact that the web "platform" is so fragmented, broken and competitive doesn't mean the resulting FUD it generates should infect other tech communities.

Comment: Also, just look at the JavaFX "newest" questions here.  Very busy.  Don't confuse the lack of activity on Oracle's forum (terrible, terrible UI) and the overwhelming success of SO (monopoly?) with a lack of interest.  :)

Comment: You can use JavaFX together CSS in order to build application with an awesome look and feel, if you are interested on how to use JavaFX together bootstrap you can find useful this link that has the mentioned integration working: https://github.com/enriquezrene/curso-javafx-udemy/tree/master/clase-18/

Answer (score 0):

I liked it a lot, but I do fear they came a bit late to the show. It is also relative complex (but nicer than swing, I find) compared to web frontend frameworks

On the last devoxx conference, Oracle profiled javaFX as a platform for mobile. Maybe it has a chance there.

For tutorials: just google....

Comment: It's only late to compete with HTML5 in browsers.  And HTML5 has basically lost on mobile to native apps.  FX on the other hand is still a pretty good solution for desktop or webstart (especially on intranets).

How bad does the HTML "platform" (HTML5 is just a hype term for a new spec) have to be to lose out against a solution that requires you to write the *same exact application two (or even three) times natively*?  

FX + Gluon (and also Apache Flex + AIR) actually have a pretty big advantage there, if people choose to use them.